# c# - Console App - Solving error when user presses enter without any numbers

Tags: c#, console-application

The title is a bit messy in regards to getting what I want out there and it's my first time on here.

Basically I have converted my string into an int :

```
string _val = Console.ReadLine();
tempScoreToWin = Convert.ToInt32(_val);
```

And what I want to know is when user a presses enter without entering a value an error will occur and the application will end.

How can I get around this?

Here is my full code:

```
while (true)
{                                                                                                               //This will allow the player to manually change the score.
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    string _val = "";
    ConsoleKeyInfo key;
    do
    {
        key = Console.ReadKey(true);
        if (key.Key != ConsoleKey.Backspace)
        {
            double val = 0;
            bool _x = double.TryParse(key.KeyChar.ToString(), out val);
            if (_x)
            {
                _val += key.KeyChar;
                Console.Write(key.KeyChar);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Backspace && _val.Length > 0)
            {
                _val = _val.Substring(0, (_val.Length - 1));
                Console.Write("\b \b");
            }
        }
    }

    while (key.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter);

    Console.WriteLine();

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------

    tempScoreToWin = Convert.ToInt32(_val);                                           // Converting the users input (Console.ReadLine()) into an integer.

    if (tempScoreToWin > 0)                                                                         // If the users input is higher than zero ... 
    {
        scoreToWin = tempScoreToWin;                                                                // Reset the scoreToWin variable with the value of tempScoreToWin.
        Console.WriteLine("The score has been set to {0}.", scoreToWin);                            // Let the user know that the score has been changed successfully.
        break;                                                                                      // Break out of the while loop.
    }

    else
    {                                                                                               // If the player has not put a correct integer in ...
        Console.WriteLine("The score has been set at a default of {0}.", scoreToWin);               // then the score will be set to the default value of scoreToWin
        break;                                                                                      // Break out of the while loop.
    }      
}
Console.ReadLine();

Console.Clear(); 

//-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Cheers!

Comment: Take a look on `Int32.TryParse` method.

Comment: What do you want to happen instead?

Comment: Also there is a button that looks like `{}` in the editor that allows you to mark sections of your post as code. I'd edit the code blocks to neaten them up but you look like you are actively editign your post at the moment so don't want to accidentally lose any changes you are making.

Comment: hi, an Invalid Message to pop up or something, tell the player to enter a number again... Also how do I get my code to display properly on here?

Comment: Why are you trying to handle backspace yourself? Just use `Console.Readline` then `TryParse`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `TryParse` will allow you to parse a string for an integer while also checking if it succeeded.

```
if(int.TryParse(_val, out tempScoreToWin)
{
    //Parse succeeded
}
else
{
    //Parse failed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Brilliant! That worked MrZander. Thank you guys so much for the quick answer. I really appreciate it :)

```
if (int.TryParse(_val, out tempScoreToWin))
                {
                    if (tempScoreToWin > 0)                                                                         // If the users input is higher than zero ... 
                    {
                        scoreToWin = tempScoreToWin;                                                                // Reset the scoreToWin variable with the value of tempScoreToWin.
                        Console.WriteLine("The score has been set to {0}.", scoreToWin);                            // Let the user know that the score has been changed successfully.
                        break;                                                                                      // Break out of the while loop.
                    }

                    else
                    {                                                                                               // If the player has not put a correct integer in ...
                        Console.WriteLine("The score has been set at a default of {0}.", scoreToWin);               // then the score will be set to the default value of scoreToWin
                        break;                                                                                      // Break out of the while loop.
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    //Parse failed
                }
```